How to offset, align and increase padding of dendogram labels
I am trying to create a dendogram in R. As of now, I have used the factoextra package, and specifically the fviz_dend function. The code is as follows:
num_data_scaled <- scale(num_data)

res.hc <- eclust(num_data_scaled, FUNcluster = "hclust", hc_metric = "euclidean", hc_method = "ward.D2", k = 6)
fviz_cluster(res.hc, geom = "point")

p <- fviz_dend(res.hc, horiz = T, cex = 0.6)

ggplotly(p)

This produces the following dendogram

As you can see, the labels are illegible, even when zoomed in. Therefore, I am trying to do the following:

Offset the labels to the right
Align the labels to the left
Increase padding at the top and bottom, ideally both on the labels and the graph itself (so that the labels are still aligned to the leaves)

I have tried to do this in various ways, both using factoextra, ggplot2 (since this is what factoextra makes its graphs in), and dendoextra. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to do what I am trying to achieve. After having spent quite some hours using trial and error, looking online for similar questions and reading the official documentation of the packages, I have decided to ask online for help.
As a sidenote, while I used factoextra, I am not disinclined to use some other way to create the dendogram, as long as it retains the same visual style (i.e. the fact that clusters are coloured). My only requirement is that I am able to eventually use plotly (whether that be ggplotly or base plotly), to be able to zoom into the indiviual clusters.

I couldn't find a built-in method to make this work, as is usually the case in the ggplot to plotly conversions.
I did come up with a work around.
Since the text size is something you may want to change, note in the code there are 2 values to the right of <<-. The first is the text size (set to 10 in my code) and text position (with is "middle right" in my code - - which equates to left justified).
Here's the UDF to fix the plot
fixer <- function(plt) {
  plt <- plotly_build(plt)                          # make sure the plots built
  lapply(1:length(plt$x$data), function(j) {        # for each trace in plot
    if(isTRUE(plt$x$data[[j]]$mode == "text")) {    # if it's a text trace
      plt$x$data[[k]]$textfont$size <<- 10               # set new font size
      plt$x$data[[k]]$textposition <<- "middle right"    # set text alignment
    }
  })
  plt                                               # return the updated plot
}


To use this function, call it when you call the plot.
ggplotly(p) %>% fixer()

You didn't provide data, but here's what this looks like using the data USArrests

